# Angular ngClick cannot access variable in a different scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am completely new to Javascript and especially AngularJs. Here is my problem, I need to call ng-click function inside ng-repeat to hide a some html outside of it.

As I understand the problem is because all of the variables (in this case specifically variable "locations") is in another scope which I cannot access. Can anybody help me with the shortest way possible to go around this problem?

I have managed so far to almost finish my website with only angular html tags (meaning I didn't really have to write any custom functions) and this is the absolute last piece.

Also, as I understand whenever a new controller in angular is created, it has its own scope. In this case, all of the calls (besides the one that I am having problems with) have been made without initializing any of the controllers, so how do you access variables? Is there something like a "default Scope"? I know rootScope did not work for me.

Thank you in advance.

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <div id="top_nav_right">    
        <div id="page_header" ng-show="checked" ng-switch on="page">
        </div>  
        <a href="#" ng-click="checked = ! checked">
        </a>
    </div>      
</div>  
<div id="main_sidebar" class="check-element animate-hide" ng-show="checked">
    <ul class="menu" ng-show="!locations">
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu" ng-show="locations">
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="sub_sidebar" ng-show="checked" ng-switch on="page">
        <div ng-switch-default "check-element animate-hide">
                <div id="latest_trips_container">       
                    <div ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">  
                                <ul id="latest_trips" ng-controller="MyCtrl">   
                                    <li ng-repeat="post in travels">
                                                <div id="trip_details">
                                                    <a id="details" href="#/details" ng-click="locations =! locations"></a>
                                                </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>              
</div>
```

Comment: Why did rootscope not work? What have you tried?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. It was as if the variables were not in rootScope at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a controller surrounding both HTML fragments:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->
</div>
```

The controller will define the locations property, but *inside* another object (let's call it `viewState`):

```
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.viewState = {
        locations: false
    };
};
```

Then bind to the inner `locations`:

```
<ul class="menu" ng-show="!viewState.locations">
</ul>
<ul class="menu" ng-show="viewState.locations">
</ul>
...
<a id="details" href="#/details" ng-click="viewState.locations = !viewState.locations">
```

---

The reason for this, and why it didn't work for you with the `$rootScope` is how scopes inherit the properties of their parents through Javascript's prototypical inheritance. Roughly and really shortly:

When you *read* a property from a scope and that scope does not contain this property, JS will look at its prototype (again *very roughly* speaking, the scope's parent scope). The chain continues up to the `$rootScope`. So, putting `locations` in the `$rootScope` will result in successful reading of this property.

Whenever you *write* a variable to a scope, it is written directly to that scope, no matter where it was read from. So changing `locations` in the inner scope has no effect in the outer scope (e.g. `$rootScope`).

Putting the variable inside an object results in reading the object, which resolves to the correct scope, then writting the property to the correct object.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it will come to this (as I was searching more info about it), I was just reluctant to go this way as it means that the way I use angular is wrong in itself. 

But thanks once again. It is clear to me.

Comment: To be honest, I don't like mixing application logic in the view. I always try to separate the logic from the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. It seems extremely simple but maybe it will help others who are beginners as well. This is basically the code for making values accessible in different controllers. It is the same as Nikos suggested if I understood it correctly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.value('Pages',{page:"My Profile"});
    myApp.value('Menu',{show:false});
    myApp.value('Menu2',{show2:false});

    myApp.controller('MainMenu', function($scope,Menu,Pages) {
        $scope.menu = Menu;
        $scope.pages = Pages;
    });

    myApp.controller('MainSidebar', function($scope,Menu,Menu2,Pages) {
        $scope.menu = Menu;
        $scope.menu2 = Menu2;
        $scope.pages = Pages;
    });

    myApp.controller('SecondSidebar', function($scope,Menu,Menu2,Pages) {
        $scope.menu = Menu;
        $scope.menu2 = Menu2;
        $scope.pages = Pages;
    });


    myApp.controller('TripsFx', function($scope,Menu2,Pages) {

        $scope.menu2 = Menu2;
        $scope.pages = Pages;
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do to have an  accessible Rootscope.

Set up Rootscope in app.run: (Don't forget to inject $rootScope)

```
    var myApp = angular.module('ProGen', []);
    myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
      //setup Rootscope
      $rootScope.locations = false;
    })
```

Create a Controller with a function that changes Rootscope ($rootscope injected too)

```
    function someCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
      $scope.travels = [
        {dest: 'Rome'},
        {dest: 'London'}
        ];

      $scope.flipMenu = function() {
        $rootScope.locations = !$rootScope.locations;
      }

    }
```

So this is the html:

```
    <html ng-app>
            {...}
    <body>
      <div id="main_sidebar">
        <ul class="menu" ng-show="!locations">
          <li>x1</li>
          <li>x2</li>
          <li>x3</li>
          <li>x4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu" ng-show="locations">
          <li>y1</li>
          <li>y2</li>
          <li>y3</li>
          <li>y4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div ng-click="locations =! locations">Change me (no Controller)</div>

      <div ng-controller="someCtrl">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="post in travels">
            <div ng-bind="post.dest" ng-click="flipMenu()"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

And this is the JS:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('ProGen', []);
  myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    //setup Rootscope
    $rootScope.locations = false;
  })

function someCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.travels = [
    {dest: 'Rome'},
    {dest: 'London'}
    ];

  $scope.flipMenu = function() {
    $rootScope.locations = !$rootScope.locations;
  }
}
```

You will find a working Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ygLlIoE55aI5q8Wkicc5?p=preview

Not sure if this what you wanted. But I hope it helps anyway.
(Don't yell at me that this is against Angular Zen, because of reasons:-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it by using what is called Factory I guess. :) 

The thing is that it's basically the same logic behind using $rootScope and creaiting a Factory with accessible values so I just went the way that is as I understood more conventional. :)

I was trying to use $rootScope so I would avoid rewriting the whole logic behind my angular but I had to do it anyway, so I create separate controllers for all the chunks that I use and just passed the necessary values where it was needed. But once again thanks for your effort :)